# My program keeps crashing on emulator

Tags: java, android

I'm sorry bad English.
I'm new to android studio and Java.
This one maybe basic, but none of the answer from other same questions solve my problem.
it's says that my main activity and other activity is not an abstract method and does not override the abstract method on `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

So I found some solutions that fix the problem by changing those activity to abstract or implement the method. But the program crash and stopped when being initialized on emulator. I cant find any solution, I've read the log cat and can't figure what's wrong with my code.

any help?

here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.andik.inibudi;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Gallery;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toogle);
        toogle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public boolean onNavigationsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.gallery) {
            Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.andik.inibudi.Gallery.class);
            startActivity(searchIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
        } else if (id == R.id.fileimport) {
            Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FileImport.class);
            startActivity(searchIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
        } else if (id == R.id.slideshow) {
            Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SlideShow.class);
            startActivity(searchIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

and this is my log cat:

```
11-01 05:22:41.367 6008-6008/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.andik.inibudi, PID: 6008
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.andik.inibudi/com.example.andik.inibudi.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class RelativeLayoutLayout
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class RelativeLayoutLayout
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class RelativeLayoutLayout
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.RelativeLayoutLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.andik.inibudi-9Kf2k2xmP7LCW9vSmyH9Lg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:703)
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:965)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:995)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
```

Comment: In the `activity_main` layout, you have a `<RelativeLayoutLayout>` element. It's just `<RelativeLayout>`. You've got one too many `Layout` in the name.

Comment: thank you , it worked , i missed that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you didn't correctly override the [`NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.html). You adding the following method:

```
public boolean onNavigationsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
}
```

But it should be:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
}
```

Another error as @mike-m pointing out, you also have a wrong layout view:

```
RelativeLayoutLayout
```

it should be

```
RelativeLayout
```

Comment: It's really a pleasure that I can help my fellow Indonesian ;)